# cfloop and dynamic variables from database

Tags: coldfusion

I have a small form that loops from 1 to 30 and assigns variables. After these variables are saved to the database, I am having some trouble figuring out how to set the value of the input as the value from the database. Here is a some of my code.

```
<cfloop index="i" 
    from="1" 
    to="30">

    <select name="supply_#i#"
        id="supply_#i#" 
        />
            <cfloop query="GetDescriptor">
                <option value="#GetDescriptor.Code#">
                    #GetDescriptor.Descriptor#
                </option>
            </cfloop>
    </select>

    <input type="text"
        name="quant_#i#"
        id="quant_#i#"
        />

</cfloop>
```

Once complete, the user saves all 30 values to the database. When they attempt to view or edit the form, I need to show the previously selected value. I really don't know how to "nest" coldfusion variables together, or if it is even possible, but here is an example of the VIEW/EDIT .cfm that does not work, but shows you what I am trying to accomplish with the values.

```
<cfloop index="i" 
    from="1" 
    to="30">

    <cfset "supply_#i#" = #QUERY.supply#i##>
    <cfset "quant_#i#" = #QUERY.quant#i##>

    <select name="supply_#i#"
        id="supply_#i#" 
        />
            <cfloop query="GetDescriptor">
                <option value="#GetDescriptor.Code#" 
                        <cfif #VARIABLES.supply_#i## EQ '#GetDescriptor.Code#'>
                            SELECTED="SELECTED"
                        </cfif> >
                    #GetDescriptor.Descriptor#
                </option>
            </cfloop>
    </select>

    <input type="text"
        name="quant_#i#"
        id="quant_#i#"
        value ="#VARIABLES.quant_#i##"
        />

</cfloop>
```

Comment: What is the actual structure of the db table the values are inserted into? The variable names suggest you are using a denormalized db design.  Also, can there be less than 30 entries saved?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to use array notation. That is, use brackets instead of dots. Since all variables scopes are structs you can do this.

```
variables["foo"]
```

is equivalent to

```
variables.foo
```

So in your case, you probably want to reference

```
#VARIABLES["supply_#i#"]#
```

or, perhaps

```
#VARIABLES["supply_" & i]#
```

Comment: @gt650r - Associative array notation also applies query column names. Though when used with query objects, you must specify both a column name and row number. ie `queryName["supply_" & i][ i ]` (and obviously validate row `i` exists in the query).  That said, I would recommend using a more normalized table structure. Store the data in rows, rather than columns.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for comments)

What is the actual structure of the db table the values are inserted into? The variable names suggest you are using a denormalized db design. If so, consider normalizing the structure and storing the data in rows (SupplyCode, Quantity), rather than columns (Supply1,Qty1,Supply2,Qty2,....). The normalized structure is a lot easier to query, and supports as many or as few entries as needed.

Simply query the table and use a query loop to display the existing values. Use `currentRow` in place of the index variable `i`:

```
<cfquery name="existingEntries" ...>
     SELECT  SupplyCode, Quantity
     FROM    YourTable
     ORDER BY .....
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="existingEntries">
    <select name="SupplyCode_#currentRow#" id="SupplyCode_#currentRow#">
       <cfloop query="GetDescriptor">
           <option value="#GetDescriptor.Code#" 
               <cfif existingEntries.SupplyCode EQ GetDescriptor.Code>
                        SELECTED="SELECTED"
               </cfif>>
                #GetDescriptor.Descriptor#
            </option>
        </cfloop>
    </select>

  <input type="text" name="Quantity_#currentRow#" value ="#existingEntries.Quantity#" .... />
</cfloop>
```

**NB:** Typically you would store a FK ID from the GetDescriptor table, ie "SupplyID" rather than a string code or description, ie "SupplyCode"